# Online payment implementation - paying product owner directly for items purchased from them

Tags: java, paypal, payment-gateway, finance

This is a scenario to one of the system I'm currently developing:

> I have a platform where users can
>   register and place their product
>   online, provide a price and buyers can
>   add a product to the shopping cart.
>
> On checkout, the buyer enters their
>   credit card information on a secure
>   (https) protocol.

My question is this:

How do implement the way that (when the purchasing is successful) the product owner can receive the money to his account? Don't forget that the shopping cart can contain products from many different vendors so the vendors must receive their money after purchasing. Is there a facility that allows me to take a credit card of the buyer, and check whether the payment is approved, split the amounts paid to the vendors amount they need from the purchase done by the buyer?

Also, I need to keep this as a transaction history.

I'm doing this in Java and I have no clue on online payment processes/procedures.

Thanks in advance.

**PS** I don't have a US Bank Account. For now, it caters for South African market.

**Edit** For South African companies, we have to apply for a Business account, which allows us to either purchase items online via internet banking (that means that online shops have to have a provide their account details online for the buyer to do online purchasing via internet banking) or through an online payment gateway such as [PayGate](http://www.paygate.co.za/index.php).
Unfortunately, each banks here have certain **trusted** payment gateways they stick with and it other banks may not be affiliates to these payment gateways.

PayPal facility is not yet available in South Africa, [FNB](https://www.fnb.co.za/) is busy negotiating with PayPal (actually eBay) to bring the facility here. If successful, only FNB will have PayPal support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to implement the payment APIs of any major third party providers that are available to you. You then will need your customers to provide their API credentials to you so you can connect to these APIs representing them. That will allow payment to go straight to them.

**Problem:** If these API allow for refunds there is nothing to stop you from essentially taking money from these accounts by issuing refunds. This will naturally discourage anyone with half a brain from using your service.

Based on your location this may not be a service you will able to provide as is. You may need to find a partner in a country that has Paypal, Amazon, and/or Google payment services available to them. That way you can implement middle man payment options.

Comment: So, all the vendors will have to register to the API too? What if they don't want that option?

Comment: They wouldn't have a choice really. Unless you want to handle all payments and then pay the vendors. But in that case you risk getting too many chargebacks and getting shut down. Then all of your vendors are out of luck.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a programming question yet.  You don't know (or haven't told us) enough about how credit card companies work in your country.

Or is your question really: "How can I separate a list of orders by vendor?"

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've updated the question and hope you will understand.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a US bank account. Amazon hav payments which are specifically tendered to this kind of feature.

[List of Features](http://aws.amazon.com/fps/)

Comment: No, I'm from South Africa and Amazon and PayPal facility don't apply here.